# Detect Mobile app not mobile browser in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, cordova

i have my backend api setup in Codeigniter 3 which is used by browser as well as app (built using apache cordova). i want to know how do i detect if the api request is made by mobile app or by a browser (mobile or desktop)??

Comment: It's not reliably determinable, as the user agent can be spoofed... but it's the best option you have

Comment: If you own the app as well, then maybe you can inject some custom header when accessing the site from it? Then in PHP, if the header is present, it's the app.

Comment: I had thought about the header solution but the problem is then someone could make the same request from postman using the same custom header.

Answer (score 0):

In your app, add a new header or change userAgent so you can verify in your backend where the request is coming from.